# Unable to get JFormattedTextField to highlight on mouse click focus event

Tags: java, swing, highlight, jformattedtextfield

I have been trying with no luck to get a JFormattedTextField to highlight on mouse click. I have been able to get it to work fine while tabbing through fields, however I would like to highlight everything on clicking.

I am only able to highlight on mouse click if I click and hold for about 1.5-2 seconds on the text field; I have no idea why.

I've searched and tried a few fixes including extending the class;

```
class HFTextField extends JFormattedTextField
{
    HFTextField(MaskFormatter formatter)
    {
        super(formatter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void processFocusEvent(FocusEvent e)
    {
        super.processFocusEvent(e);
        if (e.getID() == FocusEvent.FOCUS_GAINED)
        {
            this.selectAll();
        }
    }
}
```

I am also defining a (rather verbose!) FocusListener which uses SwingUtilities.invokelater;

```
public static FocusListener CreateHighlightTextFieldFocusListener(final JTextField text_field)
    {
        FocusListener fl =
                new FocusAdapter()
                {
                    public void focusGained(FocusEvent evt)
                    {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                text_field.selectAll();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };

        return fl;
    }
```

and this is the function that creates formatted text fields;

```
public static JTextField CreateFormattedTextField(int x, int y, int width, int height,
                            Method action_method, Method changed_method, Method remove_method,
                            Method update_method, String mask_formatter, String banned_chars)
    {
        MaskFormatter formatter = null;

        try {

            formatter = new MaskFormatter(mask_formatter);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            assert(false);
        }

        if(banned_chars != null)
            formatter.setInvalidCharacters(banned_chars);

        JTextField text_field = new HFTextField(formatter);

        text_field.setBounds(x, y, width, height);

        if(action_method != null)
        {
            text_field.addActionListener(CreateTextFieldActionListener(action_method, text_field));
        }

        text_field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(
                CreateTextFieldDocumentListener(changed_method, remove_method,
                                                update_method, text_field));

        text_field.addFocusListener(CreateHighlightTextFieldFocusListener(text_field));

        return text_field;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: adding a focusListener and invoking the selectAll in focusGained is the solution that works - normally :-) If it doesn't in your context, a small runnable example that demonstrates the problem is needed to track down the difference.

Comment: as an aside: no need to hard-code a reference to the textField - the event has a method getComponent to get hold of its sender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you have got problems with EDT,

how method you use for/how you added value to JTextField

works with JTextField, JFormateddTextField, with JComboBox too, and with AutoCompleted   funcionalies http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AutocompleteTextField.htm

```
   private FocusListener focsListener = new FocusListener() {

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        dumpInfo(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        //dumpInfo(e);
    }

    private void dumpInfo(FocusEvent e) {
        //System.out.println("Source  : " + name(e.getComponent()));
        //System.out.println("Opposite : " + name(e.getOppositeComponent()));
        //System.out.println("Temporary: " + e.isTemporary());
        Component c = e.getComponent();
        if (c instanceof JFormattedTextField) {
            ((JFormattedTextField) c).requestFocus();
            ((JFormattedTextField) c).setText(((JFormattedTextField) c).getText());
            ((JFormattedTextField) c).selectAll();
        } else if (c instanceof JTextField) {
            ((JTextField) c).requestFocus();
            ((JTextField) c).setText(((JTextField) c).getText());
            ((JTextField) c).selectAll();
        }
    }

    private String name(Component c) {
        return (c == null) ? null : c.getName();
    }
};
```

Comment: you are welcome, but note: be sure and avoid with mixing FocusListener and another Listeners, for example for JComboBox is FocusListener with ItemListener deadlock combination

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
 yourTextField.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
                public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                            yourTextField.selectAll();              
                                    }
                            });
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I hate to give a simple answer, but have you tried using the MouseListener interface (or MouseAdapter class)?

Have you tried something like this:

```
fieldName.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            JTextComponent text = (JTextComponent) e.getSource();
            text.selectAll();
        }      
    });
```

Also, I would not recommend doing this asynchronously.

Comment: That doesn't work either. It still only highlights if I click and hold for about a second or so.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, it would be difficult to see where things are getting bogged down. My best guess would be that you are introducing a convoluted loop through a listener. Add some debug prints to you code, especially to your listeners, and see where the explosion of print statements occurs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want specialized behavior for a mouse click, then add a MouseAdapter to your JTextFiled, and in the mouseClicked event handler, explicitly alter the background.

Answer (score 1):

basically you can use this code (not sure that for each formatter and input masks), but for Number, Date and String you can use following, with ensure that this JFormattedTextField doesn't implements AutoCompleted

```
    myTextField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            myTextField.requestFocus();
            myTextField.setText(myTextField.getText());
            myTextField.selectAll();
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        }
    });
```

sure you can pack that into InvokeLate...

Comment: nobody know what/which Listeners you added to JTextField, and isn't there way to change that by using regular JFormattedTextField, because for todays Java6 this code look like as S*a*d*o* - *M..., hmmm maybe I'll post another class that you'll try pass to your aka JTextField code

Comment: and you can add `DocumentListener` http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html on fly or is if there needed, then you FocusListener should be look like as `myText.removeDocumentLister(myDocumentListener)` then any woodoo for higlight JTextFields contents thenafter add `DocumentListener`